# Determining the order of the pole of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I am failing to understand how is pole of the function
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-i)(e^{\pi z} + 1)}
$$
is $i$ with order of 2? Thing that is confusing me is how it can be order of 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $1/f(z)=(z-i)(e^{\pi z}+1)=(z-i)g(z)$ say. Obviously $z-i$
has a simple zero at $i$. Now consider $g(z)=e^{\pi z}+1$. Then $g(i)
=e^{\pi i}+1=0$ and $g'(i)=\pi e^{\pi i}=-\pi\ne0$. Therefore $g(z)$
also has a simple zero at $z=i$. Therefore $1/f(z)$ has a double zero at
$z=i$. Thus $f(z)$ has a double pole at $z=i$.